# Running a java profiler

Tags: java

I am trying to run a java based java profiler to find out what uses up resources on my java application on my dedicated machine. The profiler I am trying to use is called warmroast.

I get the following error from running.

```
java -jar warmroast.jar

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/attach/AttachNotSupportedException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more
```

I think this error is caused by running the file with jre instead of jdk.

I have installed java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.55-2.4.7.1.el6_5.x86 as a yum package.

```
[root@ ~]# java -version
java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.4.7.1.el6_5-x86_64 u55-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

I think to fix this problem, I will need to run the jar file using jdk. Is there some kind of a jdk path to the jdk bin file? If so, what is it in centos? I've googled for a while and came up with dozens of wrong paths. I feel stupid because I think jre is a part of jdk and jdk is only using for compiling stuff and I don't think you can run files with jdk...
...
...

Comment: Usually, you should go to the JDK path, then go to JRE lib.

Comment: I am trying to find out what the jdk path is in centos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class that could not be found is in `tools.jar` in your JDK. This library is usually not automatically on the class path, even if you use JDK instead of JRE.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/sk89q/warmroast), on Linux warmroast should be started as follows (replace `PATH_TO_JDK` with the path to your JDK):

```
java -Djava.library.path=PATH_TO_JDK/jre/bin -cp PATH_TO_JDK/lib/tools.jar:warmroast-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.sk89q.warmroast.WarmRoast --thread "Server thread"
```

Here, `tools.jar` is manually added to the classpath.

Comment: How did you guys know the full file name? I've never provided that

Comment: @user3646500 What file name do you mean?

Comment: Are you sure you correctly replaced `PATH_TO_JDK` in the shell command? I tried it (on windows) and it works exactly as I wrote.

Comment: warmroast-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar is the file

Comment: I've never set the path_to_jdk